# How to implement AND/OR statement logic?

Tags: binary, logic, linear-programming

I have a doubt regarding how to implement this statement with constraints:
Only if A or B or both, then C or D or both.
I want to implement it with constraints that take binary values.
This is an example:
If A then B, means that A=B;
A or B or both, means that A+B>=1.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try.

First `A => B` is not the same as `A=B`. It is however the same as `B >= A`. If we want: `A <=> B` then indeed `A=B`.

The real question seems to be: `A+B>=1 <=> C+D>=1` or

```
A+B>=1 => C+D>=1
A+B=0 => C+D=0
```

We can write this as a system of inequalities:

```
C+D >= A
C+D >= B
C+D <= 2(A+B)
```

All variables are assumed to be binary.